# Branch and bound strategy for longest path implementation

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, branch-and-bound, longest-path

I am working on a problem which i have to solve with a branch and bound algorithm. Let's say we have n gas stations with different distance values from the starting point. Stations have different profits. We want to maximize the profit but each station must be far away  at least K length. I solved this problem with a dynamic algorithm but couldn't find a solution for branch and bound algorithm. Actually, i need a good objective function to determine bound. I tried many functions but all failed. Thanks.

Example:
n=5
k=10

distance values
l1= 5, l2=15, l3=23, l4=30, l5=38

profits:
p1=7, p2=3, p3=10, p4=12, p5=6

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly typical packing problem. We can formulate it as an integer program like so. Let `x_i` be `1` if we open station `i` and `0` otherwise. Then the objective is to

```
          n
maximize sum profit_i x_i.
         i=1
```

The constraints are that we not open two stations within distance `k`. We can slide a window of length `k` over the stations, emitting a constraint for each maximal subset. For distance values `l_1 = 5, l_2 = 15, l_3 = 23, l_4 = 30, l_5 = 38` and `k = 16`, we have constraints

```
x_1 + x_2       <= 1    (y_1)    { 5, 15}
x_2 + x_3 + x_4 <= 1    (y_2)    {15, 23, 30}
x_3 + x_4 + x_5 <= 1    (y_3)    {23, 30, 38}.
```

Finally, each station is open or not.

```
for all i, x_i in {0, 1}
```

#### Duality

The reason that we go to all of this trouble is as follows. First, we can relax the constraints by replacing `x_i in {0, 1}` with `x_i >= 0`. Now we have a linear program. We know that

```
value of linear program >= value of integer program,
```

because every solution to the integer program is a valid solution to the linear program. The beautiful thing about linear programs is that they have a dual program that, under certain technical constraints, by LP duality, satisfies

```
value of dual program = value of linear program >= value of integer program.
```

This matters because the dual program here is a *minimization*, so any old solution will give us a bound on the original integer program (i.e., the problem that we actually care about).

#### Dual program

This is derived mechanically from the linear program. I'll explain it intuitively below. General version:

```
          m
minimize sum y_j
         j=1
for all i, sum over windows j containing station i of y_j >= profit_i
for all j, y_j >= 0.
```

Concrete version (dual of the concrete LP above):

```
minimize y_1 + y_2 + y_3
y_1       >= profit_1    (x_1)
y_1 + y_2 >= profit_2    (x_2)
y_2 + y_3 >= profit_3    (x_3)
y_2 + y_3 >= profit_4    (x_4)
y_3       >= profit_5    (x_5).
y_1, y_2, y_3 >= 0.
```

Intuitively, we're figuring out how much to tax each window such that building any station is a break-even proposition. The less tax that we have to collect, the less valuable the stations.

#### Primal-dual approximation

The dual program can be solved by LP (possibly to integer optimality, actually; this is a shortest-path problem in disguise). Here's an approximation algorithm that's easier to implement.

Each `y_i` is *active* if it appears on the left-hand side of an unsatisfied dual constraint. While some `y_i` is active, we increase all active `y_i`s continuously at the same rate. In practice, we figure out which constraint is satisfied first and then step time directly to that point.

Let's suppose that the constraints are as before and that

```
y_1       >= profit_1 = 1
y_1 + y_2 >= profit_2 = 2
y_2 + y_3 >= profit_3 = 4
y_2 + y_3 >= profit_4 = 5
y_3       >= profit_5 = 3.
```

Initially all variables are `0` and active. When they hit `1`, the `profit_1` and `profit_2` constraints are satisfied. Thus `y_1` is deactivated, because it participates in no other constraint. We continue to increase `y_2` and `y_3` to `2`, and then the `profit_3` constraint is satisfied. Both variables participate in the `profit_4` constraint, so they remain active. When we increase to `2.5`, the `profit_4` constraint is satisfied, and `y_2` is no longer active. We continue, increasing `y_3` to `3` for a final solution of `y_1 = 1` and `y_2 = 2.5` and `y_3 = 3`, for value `6.5`. The optimum is (e.g.) `y_1 = 1` and `y_2 = 2` and `y_3 = 3`, for value `6`.